# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un String a Image?

Tags: java

Ocupo tomar de la base de datos una Imagen pero no puedo porque dice que no puedo convetir de String a Image:

```
  public static Mascota mostrarImagen(Mascota mostrar) {

    String sql;

    java.sql.ResultSet rs;

    try {

        sql = "Select imagenMascota from TMascotas where idMascota = 2";

        rs = Conexion.getConector().ejecutarSQL(sql, true);

        mostrar.setImagenMascota(rs.getString("imagenMascota"));  

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("No se encuentra " + e);

    }

    return mostrar;
}
```

Y lo estoy guardando así:

```
    Mascota imagenMasc = new Mascota();
    Image foto = null;
    File archivo;
    try {
        JFileChooser flcAbrirArchivo = new JFileChooser();
        flcAbrirArchivo.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("archivo de imagen", "jpg", "jpeg"));
        int respuesta = flcAbrirArchivo.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (respuesta == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            archivo = flcAbrirArchivo.getSelectedFile();
            jTextField1.setText(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
            foto = getToolkit().getImage(jTextField1.getText());
            foto = foto.getScaledInstance(110, 110, 1);
            jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(foto));

        }
        imagenMasc.setImagenMascota(foto);

        Gestor.guardarImagen(imagenMasc);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrarMascota.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: cómo has guardado la imágen en la BD?, ¿base64?, ¿bytes?

Comment: Con <Binary data>

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que `setImagenMascota`, utiliza el prototipo `setImagenMascota(java.awt.Image)` (en algúna parte del mismo), no obstante tu le estás enviando un `java.lang.String`. Para crear una *Imagen* necesitas primero leer los datos de la base de datos como `java.io.InputStream`, posteriormente crear la *Imagen* analizando el flujo de bytes

```
...
mostrar.setImagenMascota(
  javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(
    rs.getBinaryStream("imagenMascota")
  )
);
...
```